# when I click on radio button it does not showing output that I want?

Tags: java

When this program run it showing deactive output by default and when I click on active button then there is nothing show. Please help me to fix this problem.

I want to develop an application that can work like this application. This is a
demo application but I am unable to fix this problem.

**Demo application:**

```
    import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
    import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Cursor;
    public class GraphicRadioButton extends JFrame{

        public  static JRadioButton active ,deactive;
        private ButtonGroup rdoBtn;
        private JFrame frame;
        private JPanel panel;
        public GraphicRadioButton()
        {
            super("Testing");
            active = new  JRadioButton("Active");
            deactive = new  JRadioButton("Deactive ", true);
            frame = new JFrame();
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            rdoBtn = new ButtonGroup();
            rdoBtn.add(active);
            rdoBtn.add(deactive);

            panel.add(active);
            panel.add(deactive);
            this.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            this.setResizable(false);
            Cursor c = new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
            this.setCursor(c); 
            pack();
        }
    }



    import javax.swing.*;
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String ar[]){
            GraphicRadioButton g = new GraphicRadioButton();
            g.setVisible(true);
            boolean test = true;
            boolean ch = true;

            do{
                 if(GraphicRadioButton.active.isSelected()&&!test){

                        System.out.println("active");
                        test = true;
                        ch = true;
                  }

                 if(GraphicRadioButton.deactive.isSelected()  &&ch ){

                        System.out.println("deactive");
                        test = false;
                        ch = false;
                    }

            }while(true);

        }//end main method
    }//end Main class
```

Comment: Hi, I have tested your class (only change is running everything in the Main class) and it works fine, what is your problem? And probably you should use a listener for this purpose.

Comment: which jdk are you using .but still  I am not fixing it .i changed !test to test but problem is same .
when i click on active radioButton then it should print active and again when i click on deactive button it should be print deactive until i did not exit the application .

Comment: I'am using Java 8, I have posted the code used as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
if (GraphicRadioButton.active.isSelected() && !test) {
```

to

```
if (GraphicRadioButton.active.isSelected() && test) {
```

You need to change `!test` to `test`.

Comment: @Zabuza same answer i gave

Comment: I edited **your answer** to improve its quality. I did not *hijack* it. Its still yours and every reputation corresponding to that answers also belongs to you.

Comment: @Zabuza i know... i am new to this.. i don't know proper editing here so i answered as a plain text... Thanks for ur help

Comment: That's fine, you're welcome :) You'll get familiar with it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with the following code and it works fine:

```
package ljm.aplication;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class GraphicRadioButton extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        GraphicRadioButton g = new GraphicRadioButton();
        g.setVisible(true);
        boolean test = true;
        boolean ch = true;

        do {
            if (GraphicRadioButton.active.isSelected() && !test) {

                System.out.println("active");
                test = true;
                ch = true;
            }

            if (GraphicRadioButton.deactive.isSelected() && ch) {

                System.out.println("deactive");
                test = false;
                ch = false;
            }

        }
        while (true);

    }// end main method

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3366748875509458022L;
    public static JRadioButton active, deactive;
    private ButtonGroup rdoBtn;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    public GraphicRadioButton() {
        super("Testing");
        active = new JRadioButton("Active");
        deactive = new JRadioButton("Deactive ", true);
        frame = new JFrame();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        rdoBtn = new ButtonGroup();
        rdoBtn.add(active);
        rdoBtn.add(deactive);

        panel.add(active);
        panel.add(deactive);
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setResizable(false);
        Cursor c = new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
        this.setCursor(c);
        pack();
    }
}
```